# Iterate multiple arrays in single foreach

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I have a set of text boxes like this:

```
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" />
```

and I am using

```
foreach ($_POST['tbxt'] as $tbxt) {
    //
}
```

But for example if I have:

```
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" /><select name="selxt[]"></select>
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" /><select name="selxt[]"></select>
<input type="text" name="tbxt[]" /><select name="selxt[]"></select>
```

So can I write something like this:

```
foreach (($_POST['tbxt'] as $tbxt) && ($_POST['selxt'] as $selxt)) {
    //
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you could just loop over them separately combining them into a common object.

Comment: If there are always the same number of each, you could do `array_combine` and then `foreach ($combined as $tbxt => $selxt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use `for` instead of `foreach`, you can do something like the following:

```
$tbxt = $_POST['tbxt'];
$selxt = $_POST['selxt']

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($tbxt); $i++) {
    //access them using $tbxt[$i] and $selxt[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a case for SPL [Multiple iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php):

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['tbxt']));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['selxt']));
foreach($mi as list($tbxt, $selxt)) {
    echo $tbxt, ' ', $selxt, PHP_EOL;
    ....
}
```

though the use of `list()` here requires PHP >= 5.5.0

You can simulate this in earlier versions by assigning a name to each iterator, then extracting within your loop:

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['tbxt']), 'tbxt');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['selxt']), 'selxt');
foreach($mi as $lists) {
    extract($lists);
    echo $tbxt, ' ', $selxt, PHP_EOL;
    ....
}
```

or

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['tbxt']), 'tbxt');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['selxt']), 'selxt');
foreach($mi as $lists) {
    echo $lists['tbxt'], ' ', $lists['selxt'], PHP_EOL;
    ....
}
```

Comment: wow this is amazing never seen this one before, i have a question. what happens if they don't have  the same size? lets say `seltxt` has only 2

Comment: @Ghost, that's where you need to read the PHP docs, and look at the flags that can be applied to Multiple Iterators to handle that case... because there's different options you can apply to say how multiple iterators should behave in that case (see `predefined constants` in the docs). You can also control how the keys tie up; but it's certainly easier to use when you have the same number of entries in each, and you can link any number of arrays using Multiple Iterators, you're not just limited to 2